# JAXB: unmarshal an XML file with a given XML schema

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a XML file, and its xml schema contains couples `complexType` in it. So when I unmarshal the xml file, I want to give the xml parser my `xml schema`. Is it possible to do it, if so, then how to do it?

**EDIT**: After I `unmarshal`, every field in my object is null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The issue you are seeing is due to the content being nested within the `NameAndAddress` element.  You could introduce a `NameAndAddress` class have `PackageLabel` hold an instance of that.

**PackageLabel**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="PackageLabel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PackageLabel implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name="NameAndAddress")
    private NameAndAddress nameAndAddress;

}
```

**NameAndAddress**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class NameAndAddress {

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="Address1")
    private String address1;

    @XmlElement(name="Address2")
    private String address2;

    @XmlElement(name="City")
    private String city;

    @XmlElement(name="State")
    private String state;

    @XmlElement(name="ZipCode")
    private String zipCode;

}
```

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s @XmlPath Extension**

Alternatively you could use the `@XmlPath` extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="PackageLabel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PackageLabel implements Serializable {

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/Name/text()")
    private String name;

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/Address1/text()")
    private String address1;

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/Address2/text()")
    private String address2;

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/City/text()")
    private String city;

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/State/text()")
    private String state;

    @XmlPath("NameAndAddress/ZipCode/text()")
    private String zipCode;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

---

You can set an XML schema on an instance of Unmarshaller.  This will cause JAXB to validate the input while it converts the XML to objects:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

If you want to generate an object model from an XML schema, you can also use JAXB to do that:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: @Harry Pham - The following may help http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/MOXy/Simple_Values/Enums.  If not go ahead and make a new question, and I can help that way.

Comment: Hi, I will post that problem separately, but mean while, can you take a look at my original post again. For some reason, after `unmarshal`, all the field in my object are all `null`. I post some code in my original post. Thank you very much, Blaise. btw, your blog is awesome.

Comment: @Harry Pham - I have updated my answer to your question.  I'm happy to hear you're enjoying the blog :).

Comment: you the developer of JAXB team, so quick question to ask. I have simple implementation of what JAXB does. So for a given XML file, I parse the tag, obtain tag name, then I put `set` in front of the tag name to generate `setter method`. For example, after parsing tag `Name`, I change it to `setName`, I then using reflection to invoke the `setName` method, like this `Method method = PackageLabel.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class); method.invoke(this, value);`. I know reflection is costly. Would you say that JAXB are doing something similar or JAXB is much more optimize than this.